# Los parámetros llegan nulos a la función

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de *ASP.NET Framework* y estoy llamando al *ActionResult* del controlador pasándole dos parámetros pero los dos parámetros llegan nulos, incluso antes de enviarlos los pinto para ver que no sean nulos, paso código:

**Vista**

```
<h6>@item.id</h6>
<h6>@Session["id"]</h6>
<form method="post">
    <a @Url.Action("Ruta", "Ruta",new {idR = item.id, idU = Session["id"]})>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Comprar</button>
    </a>
</form>
```

---

**Controlador**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Ruta(int idR, int idU)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var check = db.ReservaOrganizaRuta.FirstOrDefault(s => s.usuario_id == idU && s.ruta_id == idR);
            if (check == null)
            {
                ReservaOrganizaRuta rr = new ReservaOrganizaRuta();
                rr.ruta_id = idR;
                rr.usuario_id = idU;
                db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
                db.ReservaOrganizaRuta.Add(rr);
                db.SaveChanges();
                ViewData["doit"] = "Fet";
                
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("../Home/Index");
            }
        }
        else return RedirectToAction("../Login/Login");

        return View();
    }
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

La instrucción `@Url.Action("Ruta", "Ruta",new {idR = item.id, idU = Session["id"]}` genera una url al controlador pasando dos variables (`idR` e `idU`) en el query string de la propia url.

Para recuperar estos valores en el controlador debes configurarlo para utilizar el método GET en lugar del POST, cambiando el atributo `[HttpPost]` por `[HttpGet]`.

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestarme, pero como le paso el objeto al controlador desde la view ?

Comment: Perdona, no me había fijado bien en la vista. Estás pasando los valores en la url. Entonces bastaría con que cambies el método del Action de POST a GET para que te recoja los datos del query string. En tu código original cambia el `[HttpPost]` por `[HttpGet]`. Dime si te funciona y edito la respuesta.

Comment: Si, ya funciona, muchas gracias

Comment: Ok. He editado la respuesta para que se corresponda con la solución real.